# How many "odd committees" are there?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

There are 30 councilors in a council. Any two councilors are either friends or political opponent of each other. Each councilor has six political opponents. For a committee of three councilors, if any two of them are friends or any two of them are political opponents of each other, then the committee is called an "*odd*" committee. How many odd committees are there? (24th U.S.S.R. Math Olympiad)

Comment: A solution can be found on page $57$ of the book:
$$$$
$\qquad$Slinko -- USSR Mathematical Olympiads - 1989-1992
$$$$

Comment: I know. The point is how you understand and explain it.

Answer (score 0):

- let x denote the number of "odd" committees
- let y denote the number of other committees

then $x+y=\frac{30!}{3!27!}=4060$ we have $4060$ selections of $3$ councilors from council for a committee

consider a councilor if we want to select two other members in which
the other two members are both his friends or both his political opponents we have $\frac{6!}{2!4!}+ \frac{23!}{2!21!}=268 $ committees.

now consider each councilor so we have $30\times 28=8040 $ committees, but each odd committee mentioned three times, while others mentioned only once each.

so we have $3x+y=8040$,  now with solving $x+y=4060$ and $3x+y=8040$ we find $x=1990$

Comment: Thanks. That's it.

Comment: @WhiteHat If you like W.R.P.S's answer, you might accept and/or upvote it.